# How to make the following SQL problem more optimise and in correct way

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The .CSV file supplied has 225146 records and has the following fields:

```
FLOW_ID – The unique identifier of the traffic flow measured;
LINK_ID – The unique identifier of the road link being measured;
LINK_DESC – A description of the road link being measured;
FLOW_DIR – The direction of the traffic flow;
PERIOD_TYPE – The type of period when traffic was measured;
F00 to F33 – The traffic flow measured at each hour, i.e. 0:00, 1:00….23:00
```

this is the main table and split it to make it simple to use

[image: this is the main table and split it to make it simple to use]

I Split into three tables

1. Flow_Dim (flow_id(pk), Link_Desc, Flow_Dir) [with grouping]
2. Period_Dim (p_id(pk), period_type) [just got three values with group by (grouping)]
3. Traffic_Flow_Fact (flow_id(fk), p_id(fk), F00 to F23 then all the 24 columns of hours) [insert the  following query to make it simple]

   ```
   INSERT INTO `Traffic_Flow_Fact` 
       (`flow_id`, `period_id`, `H0`, `H1`, `H2`, `H3`)
       SELECT junk.`FLOW_ID`, p.`p_id`, SUM(junk.`F00`), 
               SUM(junk.`F01`), SUM(junk.`F02`), 
               SUM(junk.`F03`)
   FROM TempJunk junk, Period_Dim p
   WHERE p.`PERIOD_TYPE` = junk.`PERIOD_TYPE`
   GROUP BY p.`PERIOD_TYPE`, junk.`FLOW_ID`, p.`p_id`
   ```

Following is the table Traffic_Flow_Fact

I just want to know is there any other way to make hours and there traffic flow value in separate table so that I can find out following solutions -

a) What are the top 5 busiest links during hours public holidays, school holidays and normal time (school term)? What is the average traffic on those links during those periods?

b) What are the 3 least busy links during hours public holidays, school holidays and normal time (school term)?

c) What are the peak time hours for Monash Freeway links? What about Princes Way links?

I am not expecting any answers of these questions these just for reference so that you guys will what needs to be done

Comment: if you provide example data, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. images are not good for reproducible examples..

Comment: ... also why did you tag three RDMS products (MySQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL)? Looking into the question and SQL statement it seams you are using backticks which is only valid MySQL syntax..

Comment: just going to edit it. I am very new in database. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: You need to normilize but that is your own conclusion already. more or less. -> *" just want to know is there any other way to make hours and there traffic flow value in separate table so that I can find out following solutions - "*  .. What you can do is using a import/staging (import with MySQL's [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)) table like this and use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) or [stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) to import this data into the normalized tables

Comment: .. the triggers or stored procedures to convert/import into the normalized tables  after the main import is meant to avoid the need for extra round trips off data between MySQL and the application..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for replying me. just want to tell you that its a .csv with 225146 records. the data wont get updated or deleted. trigger is related with inserting the new data I guess. Let me have a look on triggers or stored  procedures.

Comment: @Strawberry : thanks for replying me. I am sorry I didnt get your comment. I think you are talking about table which is converted from csv file!!!.

Comment: *" trigger is related with inserting the new data I guess"* read mine second comment.. You still need to "insert" between the import table to the normalized tables... Using a stored procedures which you call after the import might proof more usefull in this case as a INSERT trigger might add a "little" extra overhead per record on the LOAD DATA command..

Comment: @RaymondNijland : Great I am looking into this. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: i think @Strawberry missed some parts in the question that you where looking for a normalisation import method with good performance from the "spreadsheet" data..

Comment: *"just want to tell you that its a .csv with 225146 records. the data wont get updated or deleted. trigger is related with inserting the new data I guess. "*  when the CVS data changes between imports and having unique id's you can do more or less the same trick.. but you are going to need a make and store a sha512 hash generated from the data fields so you can find differences between imports to only push changes to the normalized tables .. consider this comment as a general educational comment

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Thanks, I will keep in mind :-)